# trouble shooting if master db got into suspect or corrupted

Tags: sql-server-2008

Recently I attended an interview. The interviewer asked me what are the steps to follow if the master db got into a suspect state or if it is corupted? What is the correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

1. If SQL Server won't start, then you have to [rebuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx).
   Also on [MS CSS SQL Server Engineers blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-rebuild-system-databases-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)
2. Start in [single user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx)
3. Then you can [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175535.aspx) it

This is fundamental DBA knowledge: you should have some knowledge *before* it happens. And have practised it too